# SQL statement not returning any values

Tags: sql

My problem occurs with a specific table with 3 columns.

```
itemnr --item number (int) 7 chars like 1111111
ccyymm --century year month (int) 6 chars like 201605
amount --amount of the specific item for that year month combo.
```

Basically I want to create a table that shows the amount of the past 12 months.

I created 12 virtual tables using the following code

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE ccyymm = year(now())||right('00'||month(now()),2) -1
```

That shows me all the items with `where ccyymm = 201604`
and it works perfectly.

The problem is that when the month I am subtracting is more than the current month i have to subtract 1 from the year as well so I used the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE ccyymm = (case 
                when month(now()) < 12 
                then year(now())- 1||right('00'||month(now()),2) 
                else year(now())||right('00'||month(now()),2) -12 
                end)
```

So if i want to get 12 months ago's data the month is less than 12 it just subtracts 1 from the year so basically it has to give me `201505`. it says my SQL is valid but it returns no values yet when I look in the database there is data for that `ccyymm`.

Comment: Why all these capitals? Please, edit your post, it is disturbint, don't read it.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING AT US ?  Instead, show us sample data along with your expected output.  A picture is worth a thousand words on SO.

Comment: **MOTHER!!!!!** *Marnus is shouting at me!*

Comment: Since you need to "uncapitalize" you post, could you indent a bit you SQL query. Indentation is the key to a lot of mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE CCYYMM = (year(now()) * 100 + month(now())) - 100
```

Comment: Thank you P.Salmon you really helped me alot

Comment: Hehe so I did just now. Thank you for pointing that out 2 me.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged the question as both MySQL & SQL.

If you are using MySQL, then you could use the date functions :

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE CCYYMM = date_format(date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH), '%Y%m');
```

Answer (score -2):

In the WHERE, try smth like CCYYMM > (Now minus one year)
though I don't know exact syntax for that last part.